# Does elevation have any effect on Abodes?

Tags: godus

In Godus, it kind of seems like its better to build your people's home on the green levels, because they look the most fertile.

But followers on different levels all seem generally the same, I haven't noticed ones on a particular level doing better than others.

Does the level or color of level have any impact on belief generation or any other aspect of the followers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your village reaches a population of 800, you will unlock a card named **Superior Worshipers**. At this point, the Abodes will generate more faith, the higher their ground is.

There are no data on the exact effect, only the [cards](http://godus.gamepedia.com/Superior_Worshipers) text:

> Living on higher land will make your Followers feel closer to you, so they offer more Belief Belief.

So, at long term settlement, always try to build as high as possible. 
But depending on your economy you should just build where you can, demolish, raise and rebuild later to expand your faith-gain, due raising the terrain is a very expensive action.

Comment: anybody know how high / how much?  another thing to consider - above a certain "dark green", it's no longer considered grass, and grass lodges cannot be built (no plots appear on wide swaths of land that are too high).

Comment: would be useful to know, because if the benefit only appears going from "grass" to "mountain", then i shouldn't bother terraforming my grasslands to the highest grasslands.

Comment: While progressing, you will unlock several cards which allow you to elevate higher, or deeper. Afaik you will be able to to this up to the top.

Comment: Yes, you can continue to build above the grass layer, but the minimum plot size increases. One way to generate a lot of belief is to build houses on lower ground around a high-ground settlement. You can still add them to the settlement without having to spread out the high ground until you need more space for the settlement.